# Cannot understand this return statement

Tags: ios, xcode

Im following a tutorial on gesture recognition and it consists of making a playing card etc. I have a property named "rank" of type NSUInteger, so the guy made a function to return the rank as a string and the function looks like this :

```
- (NSString *) rankAsString {
return @[@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"][self.rank];
```

}

I really don't understand what is happening, I've never seen an array followed by a getter.

Comment: This will create array and return value at index self.rank. For example self.rank = 10 than this function will return J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return @[@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"][self.rank];
```

is equivalent to:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K", nil];
return [array objectAtIndex:self.rank];
```

The line you posted uses the new (well... not so new now) objective C literals.
`@[ ... ]` creates an `NSArray` object.
And you can access an `NSArray` object directly with the square bracket: `array[0]` for example.

Comment: @DeepAk just be careful for the deployment target of your application. For sure it must be >= 6.0. I think there is some sort of back compatibility for iOS 5.0, but I'm not sure

Comment: @DeepAk I think stackoverflow  is the right place where you can ask questions. Anyway, for basic stuff Apple documentation is usually well written. You should try to look there first. For example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1